# Android error Method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-edittext

Am new to android can any one suggest me, Where am doing wrong?
Whole ManiActiviy.java

Error is 'Method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker'

In these 3 line it is giving above error.

```
person = new Person();
person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());
```

Class code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tvIsConnected;
    EditText etName, etCountry, etTwitter;
    Button btnPost;

    Person person;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get reference to the views
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
        etTwitter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTwitter);
        btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if (isConnected()) {
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        } else {
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // add click listener to Button "POST"
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public static String POST(String url, Person person) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
            jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
            jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPost:
                if (!validate())
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
                break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http:// http://192.168.0.51:1337/sensormessage/pushSensorData?MAC=18:fe:34:a5:df:8c&OC=0&ALS=3 &POW=100"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            person = new Person();
            person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
            person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
            person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());
            return POST(urls[0], person);

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean validate() {
        if (etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

And Person.java

```
package android.hmkcode.com.android_post_json;

/**
 * Created by HP on 2/2/2017.
 */

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String twitter;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getTwitter() {
        return twitter;
    }

    public void setTwitter(String twitter) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `EditText` variables with the class `HttpAsyncTask` constructor as:

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    EditText etName;
    EditText etCountry;
    EditText etTwitter;
    Context context;

    //Constructor to get the values
    public HttpAsyncTask(EditText etName, EditText etCountry, EditText etTwitter, Context context){
       this.etName = etName;
       this.etCountry = etCountry;
       this.etTwitter = etTwitter;
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        person = new Person();
        person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
        person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
        person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());
        return POST(urls[0], person);

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And pass editext variables inside as:

```
new HttpAsyncTask(etName, etCountry, etTwitter, MainActivity.this).execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access view in background thread(Worker thread)

you can modify your code like this

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            person = new Person();
            person.setName(urls[1]); //name
            person.setCountry(urls[2]); //country
            person.setTwitter(urls[3]); // twitter
            return POST(urls[0], person);

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and call like this

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet",etName.getText().toString(),etCountry.getText().toString(),etTwitter.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Your cannot access the UI component in worker thread(as doInBackground creates a worker thread) unless you use Looper. 
**Solution 1:**
Inside **onPreExecute()** method you can access ui components as it run in UI thread itself. Do the following

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Person person;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        person = new Person();
        person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
        person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
        person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return POST(urls[0], person);

    }
```

**Solution 2**
Just create a Person after onClick and pass the person object in the constructor of the AsynTask()

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPost:
                if (!validate())
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                person = new Person();
                person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
                person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
                person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                new HttpAsyncTask(person).execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
                break;
        }

    }
```

And in the constructor you need the following.

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Person person;
    Context context;

    //Constructor to get the values
    public HttpAsyncTask(Person person, Context context){
       this.person= person;
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return POST(urls[0], person);

    }
```

Comment: If anyone is down voting the answer...atleast mention the reason in comments